Powershell Online Start-ComplianceSearch Issue: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
I'm trying to run the Start-ComplianceSearch cmdlet and getting this error:
`Exception             :
Type    : System.Exception
Message : |Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.ThrowTerminatingErrorException|Unable to execute the task.
Reason: Compliance search initialization for "Forma" failed with exception: Object reference not set to an instance of
an object..
HResult : -2146233088
CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Start-ComplianceSearch], Exception
FullyQualifiedErrorId : [],Write-ErrorMessage
InvocationInfo        :
MyCommand        : Write-ErrorMessage
ScriptLineNumber : 1191
OffsetInLine     : 13
HistoryId        : 5
ScriptName       : C:\Users\chill.INTRADATECH\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpEXO_1r03akpw.fkn\tmpEXO_1r03akpw.fkn.psm1
Line             : Write-ErrorMessage $ErrorObject
Statement        : Write-ErrorMessage $ErrorObject
PositionMessage  : At

C:\Users\chill.INTRADATECH\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpEXO_1r03akpw.fkn\tmpEXO_1r03akpw.fkn.psm1:1191 char:13
+             Write-ErrorMessage $ErrorObject
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
PSScriptRoot     : C:\Users\chill.INTRADATECH\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpEXO_1r03akpw.fkn
PSCommandPath    : C:\Users\chill.INTRADATECH\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpEXO_1r03akpw.fkn\tmpEXO_1r03akpw.fkn.psm1
InvocationName   : Write-ErrorMessage
CommandOrigin    : Internal
ScriptStackTrace      : at Write-ErrorMessage,
C:\Users\chill.INTRADATECH\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpEXO_1r03akpw.fkn\tmpEXO_1r03akpw.fkn.psm1: line 537
at CheckRetryAndHandleWaitTime,
C:\Users\chill.INTRADATECH\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpEXO_1r03akpw.fkn\tmpEXO_1r03akpw.fkn.psm1: line 1191
at Execute-Command,
C:\Users\chill.INTRADATECH\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpEXO_1r03akpw.fkn\tmpEXO_1r03akpw.fkn.psm1: line 1545
at script:Start-ComplianceSearch,
C:\Users\chill.INTRADATECH\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpEXO_1r03akpw.fkn\tmpEXO_1r03akpw.fkn.psm1: line 24713
at , : line 1
PipelineIterationInfo :
0`
I just freshly created the compliance search and I cannot start it.
brief powershell history
Any ideas?
I've tried elevating permissions to Global Admin level (we are using GDAP to work with this client's tenant).
I tried verifying my role assignments with Get-AzRoleAssignment but I got the same error:
Get-AzRoleAssignment
